# Thumbnail gallery by date and taxonomy

Tags: images, taxonomy, gallery, date

I'm having problem to create something like image gallery.

What I wanna do is, in the home page sidebar, there will be a box named photo gallery which will contain 2 or 4 images thumbnail (just like small icon).

Then, if someone clicks on the photo gallery title link, that will show the image gallery  page and the page will show  image with a title . The title will be by date and from taxonomoy category , just like [this](http://www.bbc.com/news/in_pictures/)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what aspect of this you are asking for help with, but as a developer I would create it like this:

- Create a page for each image gallery, perhaps using WordPress's built in gallery feature
- Set a featured image on each gallery page
- Create a set of relationship fields in Advanced Custom Fields, perhaps with the paid Repeater add on, to let you choose what pages you want to feature

Then the code you write for the home page template would:

1. Grab the IDs of the pages you want to feature from the custom field…
2. Get the titles, thumbnails, and permalinks of those pages…
3. And display them

[Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) is a great plugin, particularly for customizing home pages.

If you aren't a developer you will probably want to go with a plugin like NexGen Gallery which will let you create galleries and use a widget or shortcode to highlight some on the sidebar.

Hope that helps!

Comment: actually i need something like where user will be able to create  image gallery with a few image and with title through admin panel then in the gallery image page will just show only one image with the gallery title. pls consider that user is gonna create gallery randomly so at least 10 gallery will be shown from the user created latest gallery and other 10 gallery will be be shown by date like today's gallery 14july 12 july etc ... how can i do that? any idea?